# ValidationGroupDirective error Abp Framework

Tags: frameworks, abp

I am unsing ABP framework using Angular. On create user getting error of

```
R3InjectorError(IdentityModule)[ValidationGroupDirective -> ValidationGroupDirective -> ValidationGroupDirective
```

If I add this provider of module.ts, it give me circular dependency error. Do not know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you have multiple versions of the same package installed (due to updating an existing project).

Could you please try the following steps:

1. Remove `node_modules` folder
2. Remove `yarn.lock` (or `package-lock.json`)
3. Check if all `volo` and `abp` packages have the same version in `package.json`
4. Re-install all packages

If it doesn't work for you, please write your `app.module.ts` file and ABP version.